# How to prevent li's inside navbar to collapse

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar with some lis inside. I want to make my navbar responsive, when the screen get's smaller I want them to remain visible and in the same position, but now they just collapse. How can I make them stay in the same position? I tried using Bootstrap's nav class but it didn't work. Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <img src="/src/assets/img/logo.PNG" alt="">
          <h3 class="decentralised">decentralised</h3>
          <h4 class="shareholder">Shareholder management</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-a"> Shares Management</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-a"> Convertible Note</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-a"> Priced Round</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../../../variables";

.navbar {
  background-color: $white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 22px rgba(187, 203, 183, 0.2);
  height: 90px;

  .decentralised {
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #818683;
  }

  .decentralised {
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #818683;
  }

  .shareholder {
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #444a47;
  }

  .navbar-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    .nav-a {
      padding: 77px;
      font-family: Roboto Slab;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 16px;

      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;

      color: #303331 !important;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}

</style>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? Did you look at the [Navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/)?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4 indeed and yes

Comment: `navbar-header` and `navbar-right` are not Bootstrap 4 classes. What do you mean by collapse? Do you want them to hide in a collapsible mobile menu, or do you want the navbar to look the same regardless of viewport width? Please clarify the question.

Comment: I want them to look the same regardles of viewport width